# How do I adept CSS-rules to Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a header slider(meteor slides) to my own built theme in Wordpress: http://michaelpeyron.com/ but as you can see I can't make the plugin images to inherit the CSS-rules of my "div id=banner". I have tried to take away "#banner's background-image:" but that messed up the whole structure.

Another idea that occurred to me was to substitute `"background-image:url("img/banner.png");"` with `"background-image:url("<?php if ( function_exists( 'meteor_slideshow' ) ) { meteor_slideshow(); } ?>");"`
but then we need to change the css file to a php file. And Wordpress is in need of a "style.css" file.

To keep it simple; what I need help with is to add a slider where my header image is right now.

Answer (score 0):

one thing i can think of now is to use inline styles -

for example, here, for your banner div, go to the page where it's code belong, and change it to follow -

```
<div id="banner" style="background-image:url("<?php if ( function_exists( 'meteor_slideshow' ) ) { meteor_slideshow(); } ?>");">
```

and remove **#banner** 'background-image' property from your `style.css`

hope that helps in someway!

Comment: Thanks for answer! It was a good try. I should have thought of it myself. Anyway,I did as you suggested but I think I blew something because the header lost it's structure.

Comment: This is my #banner now: #banner {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 85;
   
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    min-width: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}
Do I have to delete all "background" properties?

Comment: looking at your site's code, i think that slider itself is displaying through that php code! my code was only if it's returning an image, now you just need to add **<?php if ( function_exists( 'meteor_slideshow' ) ) { meteor_slideshow(); } ?>** to wherever you want to display the slider.

Comment: But I added "<div id="banner" class="clearfix" 
style="background-image:url("<?php if ( function_exists( 'meteor_slideshow' ) ) { meteor_slideshow(); } ?>"); >", and it's still shows the images messed up.

Comment: remove that <div id="banner"></div>, and add <code><?php if ( function_exists( 'meteor_slideshow' ) ) { meteor_slideshow(); } ?></code> and see what happens